# Excel Daily Average Profit

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a table that looks like this..Just two column..Date and Profit:

Date--------------Profit

24 - March------25.00

24 - March------19.85

25 - March------5.25

26 - March------6.36

26 - March------10.18

26 - March------35.63

I basically want to calculate and display the average daily profit in one cell. Can someone help me. Please keep in mind that when i enter in new dates such as 27 - march and it's profit, it should update the average daily profit cell.

Thanks a lot