# Excel formula for average daily profit

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that has just two columns, Date and Profit:

```
Date            Profit
24 - March      25.00
24 - March      19.85
25 - March      5.25
26 - March      6.36
26 - March      10.18
26 - March      35.63
```

I want to calculate and display the average daily profit in one cell.

Please keep in mind that when I enter data for new dates such as 27 - March and it's profit, it should update the average daily profit cell.

Some days I do not make any sale; for example, if I make sales and profit for march 24, march 25 and march 27, I did not make a sale on March 26, I want it to calculate it regardless of me making a sale on a date or not. Meaning in a month that has 31 days, it should divide by 31 regardless on whether I made a sale on a specific date or not. Would that be possible?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a formula that will handle the input from the first day entered to the last day entered, or to the current day? Do you want to be able to have a cumulative calculation, or ones for each month?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Daily Average Profit](http://superuser.com/questions/894639/excel-daily-average-profit)

Comment: It looks like you posted the same question twice on the same day.  There is more explanation here, but there is an upvoted answer on the other and two substantive answers here.  The questions should be merged if they are the same.  If an existing answer solves the problem, please accept it.  If none do, please clarify why so you can get a better answer.  If the two questions are different, please edit one or both to better differentiate them.  In that case, it would be helpful to mention the other question and describe what is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dates in cells **A1:A25** and profit values in cells **B1:B25** you can use the following formula:

```
=SUM(B2:B25)/SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(A2:A25,A2:A25)>0))
```

Result as shown:

[image]

When you have more than 25 rows of data you'll need to adjust the formula ranges appropriately.

The formula calculates as follows:

`(Total profit)/ (number of different dates)`

**EDIT**

As per request, to include dates in between (not specified) you might use something like this:

```
=SUM($B$2:$B$25)/(MAX($A$2:$A$25)-MIN($A$2:$A$25)+1)
```

`(Total profit)/ (days between smallest and largest date in range)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help..it works...however i found a little problem...some days i do not make any sale....for example, it i make sales and profit for march 24, march 25 and march 27...the formula will only divide the profit by 3 because i did not make any sale on March 26.....i want it to calculate it regardless of me making a sale on a date or not..meaning a month that has 31 days, it should divide by 31 regardless on wether i made a sale on a specific date or not...would that be possible?

thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know how that works. If this solves your issue please mark as accepted answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

The profit can be summed up by using `=SUM(B2:B7)` and the number of days can be calculated by `=TODAY()-MIN(A2:A7)` which allows for a formula that would divide the two looking like:

```
=SUM(B2:B7)/(TODAY()-MIN(A2:A7))
```

If no sales have been made recently the formula will give results that decline over time as it is calculating from the date of first sale to the current date. replace `TODAY()` with `MAX(A2:A7)` to change it so that it calculates only from date of first sale to date of last sale.

Comment: Would you say that `TODAY()-MIN(A2:A7` gives one too few days? consider the first two days of the month. 2/4/2015-1/4/2015 = 1.

Comment: Yes, there should be a `+1` added to that section of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make a third hidden column to calculate the average for each date, and then to average that column.  Enter the following formula into C2 and then copy-paste it all the way down, or at least far enough that you will cover future entries. If you make this a table, and column C a calculated column, then it will automatically be entered into column C of any new rows as the table expands.

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A2) > 1, NOT(ISNUMBER(A2))), "", AVERAGEIF(A:A, A2, B:B))
```

This first checks to see if it is the first time the date has appeared in the sheet by using the [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/COUNTIF-function-4764f197-0127-49fa-9f5a-b188177b6db4?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ) function on column A but only down to the current cell.  It also checks that column A is a number with the [`NOT`](https://support.office.com/en-NZ/article/not-function-9cfc6011-a054-40c7-a140-cd4ba2d87d77) and [`ISNUMBER`](https://support.office.com/en-NZ/article/ISNUMBER-function-e2754c91-7009-4e7b-830c-182fcbdccbac?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ) functions so it does not return an error (Excel treats dates as numbers.)  Then it uses the [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ) function to average all items in column B that have matching dates.

This also allows the dates to be entered in any order and accounts for gaps.

Now in another cell, just average the column with `=AVERAGE(C:C)` to get your average daily profit.

You can then hide column C by right-clicking it and clicking Hide.  You can unhide it when you need to by selecting columns B through D and right-clicking and then clicking Unhide.